# SQL Server 2014 : View Any Definition permission be granted to role and assigned at a database level

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2014 can the "View Any Definition" permission be granted to role and assigned at a database level? I have only see it assigned at the server/user level. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you are asking about granting the ability to grant access to the catalog view metadata on a particular DB to a group instead to grant such permission for the server as a whole, correct?

Under this assumption, you can use `VIEW DEFINITION` permissions to achieve this goal, for example:

```
-- Create a role that will have access to all ,etadata (catalog views) on this database
CREATE ROLE [metadata_visibility_group]
go
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [metadata_visibility_group]
go
```

To verify if this is what you really intended, try the following:

```
-- Testing
CREATE USER [toto] WITHOUT LOGIN
go
EXECUTE ('SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules') AS USER = 'toto'
ALTER ROLE [metadata_visibility_group] ADD MEMBER [toto]
EXECUTE ('SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules') AS USER = 'toto'
go
DROP USER [toto]
go
```

You will notice that before being a member of the role, our demo user can see a limited set of modules, and very likely could not see the module definition; after becoming a member of the role, all the metadata for the modules, including the defintion are accessible.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks!  The issue is the procedure information can be see via the query above, but not in the UI.  How can I grant the ability at a database level to see the stored procs via the UI?

Comment: Granting `VIEW DEFINITION` should allow to view the stored procedures via the UI as well. You may need to refresh object browser (right-click, refresh). Notice that `VIEW DEFINITION` will only give you metadata visibility for the current database, not for all databases.

Answer (score 1):

does this help ,I am seeing below at database level(I don't have roles so assigned to public only for demo,you can assign to role you have)

```
tsql:
use [sql2016]
GO
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [public]
GO
```

[image]